# Make a selection of items in a list

Tags: c#, list

I have a DataTable which I have converted into a list.  I would like to know how to query the list and create a new list where the ParentID is null.

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
myTable.Columns.Add("ParentID", typeof(string));
myTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
myTable.Rows.Add(null, "CEO");
myTable.Rows.Add("CEO", "FD");
myTable.Rows.Add("CEO", "CIO");

List<DataRow> lst = myTable.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

I am trying something like:

```
List<DataRow> topNodes = lst.Select("ID is null")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you know the DataTable has a Select method that would do exactly what you want with out creating a list?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi - yes I have used this but would like my result in a list of DataRows

Answer (score 0):

try that, assuming you can use LINQ

```
var topNodes = lst.Where(l => (!(l.ID.HasValue))).ToList();
```

Edit:

I see your ID is `String`, so it should be like that:

```
var topNodes = lst.Where(l => ID.IsNullOrEmpty()).ToList();
```

Edit:

The list is `DataRow` so:

```
var topNodes = lst.Where(row => row["ID"].IsNullOrEmpty()).ToList();
```

Edit:

You added more information regarding what you want to do. If all you need is list or `DataRow`, I would filter first and then cast to list:

```
var topNodes = myTable.Select("ID is null").AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Comment: unless you need the structure as `DataTable` I recommend using `IList` of some type of data `Class`, then you can use LINQ to manipulate the collections

Answer (score 0):

You could try this - search for all cells in a row, for which the content is null. Note that in this case (for the given input - ParentId column is of type string) the row value has to be converted to a string:

```
// get only those items where ParentId is null      
var topRows = myTable
                .AsEnumerable()
                .ToList()
                .Where (row => string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["ParentID"].ToString()))
                .ToList();
```

Output (as List of DataRows) for the given input is:

```
ParentID    |   ID 
-------------------
null        |   CEO
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:  See comments under original post.

```
List<DataRow> lst = myTable.Select("ParentID is null").ToList();
```

Edit:  I see that my answer is very similar to Kris Ivanov's but mine is a bit simpler and doesn't use the noxious var keyword and I suggested using Table.Select first in the comments.  So, I'll leave it be.